# Angular Dependencies Confusion

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Can anyone help explain what's going as I'm not sure why when I run `npm install` it has `warning` about versions which I have both installed:
`npm install npm WARN @angular/material@12.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@12.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

[image]

As you can see I have both `material` and `cdk` version 12 I'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

**From npm version 3 onwards peer dependency automatic installation was deprecated. In order to overcome these warnings you should install peer dependencies by yourself one by one.**

**You can mitigate this error by following:**

```
npm install --save-dev {specify-peer-dependency-packages-one-by-one-here}
```